# Set the visibility of a button in ListView from ActionBar

Tags: android, button, android-listview, android-actionbar

So, I have a list with some data (subject and note). I have also a button on the same row to delete the content.

I want to make the button invisible at the beginning and when I press a button from action bar, I want the button to appear on each line. I use a custom adapter for displaying the list. The problem is that my button appears only on the first line even if I have 5 lines for example. I think that I have to handle the problem in the adapter, but I dont't know how ?

How can I make the button to appear on each line when I press the button from action bar ?

Thanks!

Comment: share your code what u tried

Answer (score 1):

From the `Activity` you should set a bool in your adapter, like: `myAdapter.setButtonVisible()`. In your setter you set a boolean value to true, and in your adapter's `getView(...)` you use this boolean to set the button's visibility when the view is generated.
The trick is the following: after you set the boolean true you have to call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method, which will tell the attached list view to refresh the items in it.

Comment: Hi. So, I put a bool in my adapter : public boolean setButtonVisible = true;. In getView() I used the bool to set the visibility when the view is generated :  if (setButtonVisible) { delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); ContentAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); }.   I try to call in my activity like this : if (contentAd.setButtonVisible) {

       Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
                    delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    contentAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }. But it is not correct. Can you give me any hint ? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of this: `if (contentAd.setButtonVisible) { Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button); delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); contentAd.notifyDataSetChanged(); }` you have to call this:
`contentAd.setButtonVisible=true;
contentAd.notifyDataSetChanged();`. The `notifyDataSetChanged` will inform the attached `listView` to redraw everything from the adapter. And in the next redraw the adapter will return with items where the delete button is visible.

Comment: thank you, I realised it two hours ago ;) you're right, I had to call contentAd.setButtonVisible=true and to notify the adapter :)

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was correct you can accept it any time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for updating the visible items:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++)
 {
        //get reference to the view and update it
        listView.getChildAt(i);
 }
```

In your adapter you should handle the state change, so it'll behave nicely when the user scrolls.